# Display image statistics in .csv

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9a51eae7306fc7695f58b0638e9f1cc2), I have displayed the statistics using hardcode i.e information is fed manually in a list and displayed.
I would like to display all statistics correctly using for loop by iself automatically.

```js
//Create a circle by drawing a 2000 m buffer around a point and saving it to variable roi.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-76.147, 43.046]).buffer(20000);

//Create a variable that points to a particular Landsat image in the Earth Engine
var myimage = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA/LT05_015030_20100531');

// Compute the mean .
var meanDict = myimage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: 90
});

// Compute the median.
var medianDict = myimage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: 90
});

// Compute the mode.
var modeDict = myimage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: 90
});

// Reduce the image to get a one-band maximum value image.
var maxValue = myimage.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

//min value
var minValue = myimage.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

// Extract the bands from collection and make a list
var bands= ee.List([
    [ 'B1','0.45','0.092377477','0.086616925','0.086616925'],
    ['B2','0.51','0.085137095','0.076246974','0.076246974'],
    ['B3','0.59','0.062736553','0.053236987','0.044920224'],
    ['B4','0.67','0.324248892','0.334150672','0.357299032'],
    ['B5','0.88','0.161820343','0.157588621','0.153408903'],
    ['B6','1.65','0.3812067','0.295290527','293.7689209'],
    ['B7','2.29','0.076728936','0.064302692','0.052958585'],
    ['B8','0.5','672.0124447','671','672']
]);

var featList=bands.map(function(list){
  return ee.Feature(null).set({bands:ee.List(list).get(0),wavelength:ee.List(list).get(1),
      mean:ee.List(list).get(2),median:ee.List(list).get(3),mode:ee.List(list).get(4)})
})

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(featList)

//Export table to Drive;
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: features, //Select FeatureCollection
  folder: 'GEE', //Set folder name
  fileFormat: 'CSV' //Set file format
});
```

Comment: Hi poorva, Welcome on SIG. If you wxant to get an answer, I suggest you refactor your question : 
- reduce the amont of code your sending to the minimum (I've already cleaned up some stuff)  
- better describe your problem in the title and in the question

Comment: okay Pierrick ...thankyou!

Comment: I basically want to know how to display the wavelength,mean,median,mode of all bands of a single image.The code which i have written doesnt use loops.I want to do it with the loops.Here is the link to my code [link] https://code.earthengine.google.com/6585a64332f06649d7c32c43c7e1b4d2  
 @PierrickRambaud   PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Don't repeat yourself in the comments it's reducing your impact. + you don't need to "ask" for help. If you there you need a hand we know that. and finally don't use capital letters, it's aggressive.

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Comment: I modified your code adding some lines for retrieving directly bands names, wavelength, mean, median and mode of all bands of a single image (and commenting your older bands variable). Unique exception was the wavelength because this information is not included in 'Metadata properties'. So, I created this list manually. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code adding some lines for retrieving directly bands names, wavelength, mean, median and mode of all bands of a single image (and commenting your older bands variable). Unique exception was the wavelength because this information is not included in 'Metadata properties'. So, I created this list manually. Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/75fe756f94f0f6451842197fc650b780) looks as follows:

```
//center the map and display the image
Map.setCenter(26.7606, 83.3732,10);
Map.addLayer(myimage);

//Display the image using a specific band combination and call image ColorIR composite.
Map.addLayer(myimage, {bands:['B4' , 'B3' , 'B2']},'colorIR composite',false);

//Define visualisation parameters to display the image in the map window.
var vizParams={
    bands:['B4' , 'B3' , 'B2'],
    min: 0,
    max: 0.5,
    gamma: [0.95,1.1,1]
};

Map.addLayer(myimage, vizParams, 'Color IR composite' ,false);

//Create a circle by drawing a 2000 m buffer around a point and saving it to variable roi.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-76.147, 43.046]).buffer(20000);
//Display the buffer
Map.addLayer(roi);

//Create a variable that points to a particular Landsat image in the Earth Engine
var myimage = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA/LT05_015030_20100531');

print("my image", myimage);

var bandNames = myimage.bandNames();
print('Band names:', bandNames);  // ee.List of band names

var properties = myimage.propertyNames();
print('Metadata properties:', properties);  // ee.List of metadata properties

//there is not information about wavelengt from bands so, it must be added manually

var waveLengthBands = ee.List(['0.45-0.52', '0.52-0.60 ', '0.63-0.69', '0.76-0.90', 
  '1.55-1.75', '10.40-12.50', '2.08-2.35', 'none']);
print('WaveLength Bands', waveLengthBands);

var myimage = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA/LT05_015030_20100531');
// Compute the mean .
var meanDict = myimage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: 90
});

// Get the mean from the dictionary and print it.
print('Mean', meanDict);

// Compute the median.
var medianDict = myimage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: 90
});

// Get the mode from the dictionary and print it.
print('Median',medianDict);

// Compute the mode.
var modeDict = myimage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: 90
});

// Get the median from the dictionary and print it.
print('Mode',modeDict);

var bands =  bandNames.map(function (ele) {
  
  var idx = bandNames.indexOf(ele);
  
  return [ele, waveLengthBands.get(idx), meanDict.get(ele), medianDict.get(ele), modeDict.get(ele)];
  
});

print("list of stats", bands);

// Reduce the image to get a one-band maximum value image.
var maxValue = myimage.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(myimage, 10);
Map.addLayer(maxValue, {max: 13000}, 'Maximum value image');

//min value
var minValue = myimage.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(myimage, 10);
Map.addLayer(minValue, {min: 0}, 'Minimum value image');

// Extract the bands from collection and make a list
/*
var bands= ee.List([
                    [ 'B1','0.45','0.092377477','0.086616925','0.086616925'],
                     ['B2','0.51','0.085137095','0.076246974','0.076246974'],
                     ['B3','0.59','0.062736553','0.053236987','0.044920224'],
                     ['B4','0.67','0.324248892','0.334150672','0.357299032'],
                     ['B5','0.88','0.161820343','0.157588621','0.153408903'],
                     ['B6','1.65','0.3812067','0.295290527','293.7689209'],
                     ['B7','2.29','0.076728936','0.064302692','0.052958585'],
                     ['B8','0.5','672.0124447','671','672']]);
*/

var featList = bands.map(function(list){
  return ee.Feature(null).set({bands:ee.List(list).get(0),wavelength:ee.List(list).get(1),
      mean:ee.List(list).get(2),median:ee.List(list).get(3),mode:ee.List(list).get(4)});
});

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(featList);
print(features);

//Export table to Drive;
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: features, //Select FeatureCollection
  folder: 'GEE_folder', //Set folder name
  fileFormat: 'CSV' //Set file format
});
```

After running above code in GEE code editor and its associated task, I got cvs file as expected. It looks as follows after it being opened with a plain text editor.

```
system:index,bands,mean,median,mode,wavelength,.geo
0,B1,0.09237747700969104,0.08661692518953008,0.08661692518953008,0.45-0.52,
1,B2,0.08513709531653076,0.07624697435362061,0.07624697435362061,0.52-0.60 ,
2,B3,0.06273655323585847,0.05323698744177813,0.04492022364556938,0.63-0.69,
3,B4,0.3242488916113202,0.33415067195892323,0.35729903211388575,0.76-0.90,
4,B5,0.1618203434605938,0.1575886209460983,0.15340890275378363,1.55-1.75,
5,B6,296.3088653679029,295.5290527343749,293.76892089843756,10.40-12.50,
6,B7,0.07672893620940532,0.06430269171473459,0.05295858501710743,2.08-2.35,
7,BQA,672.0124446914976,672.0000000000078,672.0000000000078,none,
```